# How to use C++ operators within python using boost::python (pyopencv)

Tags: c++, python, operators, operator-overloading, boost-python

I'm using the pyopencv bindings. This python lib uses boost::python to connect to OopenCV. Now I'm trying to use the SURF class but don't know how to handle the class operator in my python code.

The C++ class is defined as:

```
void SURF::operator()(const Mat& img, const Mat& mask,
                  vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints) const
{...}
```

How can I pass my arguments to that class?

**Update:**
Thanks to interjay I can call the method but now I getting type errors. What would be the python boost::python::tuple ?

```
import pyopencv as cv
img = cv.imread('myImage.jpg')

surf = cv.SURF();
key = []
mask = cv.Mat()
print surf(img, mask, key, False)
```

Gives me that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "client.py", line 18, in <module>
       print surf(img, mask, key, False)
       Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
       SURF.__call__(SURF, Mat, Mat, list, bool)
       did not match C++ signature:
            __call__(cv::SURF inst, cv::Mat img, cv::Mat mask,
                     boost::python::tuple keypoints,
                     bool useProvidedKeypoints=False)
            __call__(cv::SURF inst, cv::Mat img, cv::Mat mask)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just call it as if it was a function. If `surf_inst` is an instance of the `SURF` class, you would call:

```
newKeyPoints = surf_inst(img, mask, keypoints)
```

The argument `keypoints` is expected to be a tuple, and `img` and `mask` should be an instance of the `Mat` class. The C++ function modifies its `keypoints` parameter. The Python version instead returns the modified keypoints.

C++'s `operator()` is analogous to Python's `__call__`: It makes an object callable using the same syntax as a function call.

Edit: For your second question: As you can see in the error, `keypoints` is supposed to be a tuple and you gave it a list. Try making it a tuple instead.

Comment: Thanks interjay, that works. But now I'm getting a type error. I've updated my question. Do you have any advice on that?